# How to copy properties from source node to destination node in cq

Tags: aem

I want to get Some Property from Source Node Using getProperties()  and setProperty in another Destination Node. How can i check that property is protected or not.As if i copy all the property in destination it gives me ConstraintViolationException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to get the definition of the property:

```
PropertyDefinition propDefinition = node.getProperty("/yourprop").getDefinition();
```

on the definition you can call isProtected():

```
Boolean isPropertyProtected = propDefinition.isProtected();
```

or just inline it:

```
node.getProperty("/yourprop").getDefinition().isProtected();
```

for further reading I suggest:
http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/16_Access_Control_Management.html; 
Chapter 16.3.12 Interaction with Protected Properties

And the JCR documentation on node types:
http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/node-types.html

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because you are trying to copy all properties which includes cq:primaryType as well. If you see in crx, these basic properties are not editable.

For copy you can take a specific property and set a specific property, instead of copying and pasting all the properties.

Comment: it will not help me.I want to copy all except protected one.Want a check in which i can check whether the property is protected or not.